# problema com expressoes regulares em php

Tags: php, algoritmo-de-busca

eu estou com um problema em PHP. Eu criei um sistema de busca com php sem utilizar banco de dados. a busca funciona perfeitamente, o sistem consegue buscar uma palavra nos arquivos, o problema está na exibição  dos resultados da busca, o sistema antes exibia o nome dos arquivos, porém estou utilizando expressões regulares para exibir o title da página, caso exista. o código funciona perfeitamente apenas quando não há quebras de linhas após o . Porém, se eu der um simples enter após o  o código não funciona corretamente. Eis os códigos:

index.php

```
<form action="busca.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="s"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

busca.php

```
<?php

//verifica se existe o campo $_POST['pesquisa'] vindo do formulário
$pesq = (isset($_GET['s'])) ? trim($_GET['s']) : '';

        //verifica se o campo está vazio
        if(empty($pesq)){
            echo 'Digite no campo de Busca';
        }else{
            //pasta onde está os arquivos da pesquisa        
            $pasta = "arquivos";
            //arquivo atual
            $atual = "$pasta/busca.php";

            //faz a listagem dos arquivos da pasta indicada, e atribui a um array
            $busca = glob("$pasta/*.{php,html}", GLOB_BRACE);

            //percorre o array
            foreach($busca as $item){
                    //verifica se o arquivo não é o atual
                    if($item !== $atual){
                        //abre o arquivo
                        $abrir = fopen($item, "r");
                        //faz um loop até chegar o final do arquivo
                        while(!feof($abrir)){
                             //ler arquivo
                            $lendo = fgets($abrir);
                            //remove os caracteres html e php
                            $conteudo = $lendo;
                            $lendo = strip_tags($lendo);


                            //verifica se tem algum um item da pesquisa
                            if(stristr($lendo, $pesq) == true){
                                //remove a extensão .php
                                $dados = str_replace(".php", "", $item);
                                //retorna o nome apenas do arquivo
                                $dados = basename($dados);
                                preg_match_all('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/',$conteudo,  $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
                                $title = isset($matches[1][0]) ? $matches[1][0] : $dados;
                                //coloca o link no array
                                $result[] = '<a href="?pagina='.$dados.'">'. $title.'</a>';
                                //apaga a variavel $dados
                                unset($dados);
                            }
                            //apague a variavel lendo
                            unset($lendo);
                        }
                        //fecha o arquivo
                        fclose($abrir);    
                    }                
            }

            /*IMPRIMIR O RESULTADO*/

            //verifica seo result existe
            if(isset($result) && count($result) > 0){
                //remove os resultado iguais
                $result = array_unique($result);

                echo '<ul>';

                //percorre o array
                foreach($result as $link){
                    echo "<li>$link</li>";
                }
                echo '<ul>';
            }else{
                echo 'Nenhum resultado na busca';
            }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você estava procurando o título na mesma linha em que buscava seu termo, o que é mais difícil de acontecer, é melhor acumular todo o arquivo para fazer a busca do título, e como o Oeslei disse, faltam as flags que apontam a procura para todo o arquivo e com quebra de linha, no caso usei as duas `sm` veja:

```
<?php

//verifica se existe o campo $_POST['pesquisa'] vindo do formulário
$pesq = (isset($_GET['s'])) ? trim($_GET['s']) : '';

//verifica se o campo está vazio
if(empty($pesq)){
    echo 'Digite no campo de Busca';
}else{
    //pasta onde está os arquivos da pesquisa        
    $pasta = "arquivos";
    //arquivo atual
    $atual = "$pasta/busca.php";

    //faz a listagem dos arquivos da pasta indicada, e atribui a um array
    $busca = glob("$pasta/*.{php,html}", GLOB_BRACE);

    $lendo = "";
    $conteudo = "";

    //percorre o array
    foreach($busca as $item){
            //verifica se o arquivo não é o atual
            if($item !== $atual){
                //abre o arquivo
                $abrir = fopen($item, "r");
                //faz um loop até chegar o final do arquivo
                while(!feof($abrir)){
                     //ler arquivo
                    $lendo = fgets($abrir);
                    //remove os caracteres html e php
                    $conteudo .= $lendo;
                    $lendo .= strip_tags($lendo);

                }

                //verifica se tem algum um item da pesquisa
                if(stristr($conteudo, $pesq) == true){
                    //remove a extensão .php
                    $dados = str_replace(".php", "", $item);
                    //retorna o nome apenas do arquivo
                    $dados = basename($dados);
                    preg_match_all('/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/sm',$conteudo,  $matches);
                    //var_dump($conteudo);
                    //var_dump($matches);
                    $title = isset($matches[1][0]) ? $matches[1][0] : $dados;
                    //coloca o link no array
                    $result[] = '<a href="?pagina='.$dados.'">'. $title.'</a>';
                    //apaga a variavel $dados
                    unset($dados);
                }

                //fecha o arquivo
                fclose($abrir);    
            }                
    }

    /*IMPRIMIR O RESULTADO*/

    //verifica seo result existe
    if(isset($result) && count($result) > 0){
        //remove os resultado iguais
        $result = array_unique($result);

        echo '<ul>';

        //percorre o array
        foreach($result as $link){
            echo "<li>$link</li>";
        }
        echo '<ul>';
    }else{
        echo 'Nenhum resultado na busca';
    }

}
```

Funciona, mas recomendo rever a lógica desse código.

Comment: obrigado amigo me salvou de uma fria.

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar a flag `s` ou `m`. Seria assim: `preg_match_all('/expressao/s', ...)`.

A flag `s` serve para considerar todos os caracteres ao utilizar o `.`, incluindo newlines (que não são consideradas por padrão).

Já a flag `m` serve para considerar todas as linhas na expressão, que por padrão considera apenas uma linha de cada vez.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php